# Get value in the request generated previously by DataGenerator

Tags: soapui

it's my first question, soI'll try to explain it in details.

I have a lot of requests and values should be unique almost always, not concerning next case : Request_1 and Request_2.
There is Value_1 in Request_1 and this value generated by DataGen (Type^Number).
I want to take this value (After generation) and put it in Request_2, but I use Read mode in DataGen (it's required) and I always got unique number.

```
Request_1:

    {
       "Intent": 0,
       "RequestDetail":    {
          "Stan": "${DataGen#Stan}", **--> for ex: 1234 after generation**
          "ReferenceNumber": "${DataGen#RefNum}",
          "LocalDateTime": "2015-04-06",
          "Amount": 123,
          "CurrencyType": 0,
          "Track2": "value"
       }

    Request_2:
    {
       "Intent": 4,
       "RequestDetail":    {
          "Stan": "${DataGen#Stan}",
          "ReferenceNumber": "${DataGen#RefNum}",
          "LocalDateTime": "2015-04-06",
          "Amount": 123,
          "CurrencyType": 0,
          "OrigStan": "${Request_1#Request#$.RequestDetail.Stan}" **--> Here I hope to get '1234' but I got differet number.**
    }}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of `Stan` in `DataGen`?

Comment: System Trace Audit Number  (specific parameter for payment provider)

Comment: Sorry. I meant: what the code or source of `Stan`?

Comment: Source is DataGen --> Type<Number> --> Mode<Read> --> Start 111111-->End 999999. Randomize instead of step

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the value *after* it gets evaluated. This is done with the "RawRequest" parameter, like so:

```
"OrigStan": "${Request_1#RawRequest#$.RequestDetail.Stan}"
```

Some older versions of SoapUI have a bug where the above will not work as expected. I am not sure when the bug got fixed, and it is possible it may have slipped back in.

You can use a work around.

One possibility is to use an extra transfer test step, to transfer the value from your data source into a test case property, and then have all your test steps refer to this *stable* property.
Official [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/transferring-properties.html) is here.

Another possibility is to have two data source loops, one loop generates all your data as you have done now, and and the second loop collects all the data. This second loop will again be *stable*, and you can use the value from that one safely.
This is described in [more detail](http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/tips---tricks.html#2-3-Randomizing-DataSource-rows) the SoapUI tips and tricks section.

Comment: Thank you, will try tommorow.

Comment: Does not work for me, SoupUI always take random value

Comment: Thank you for your time. There is more then 200 steps. Yes, workaround works for me.